# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError for simple rdd.count() operation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a simple count operation working on about 55 files on hdfs and a total of 1B records. Both spark-shell and PySpark fail with OOM errors. I'm using yarn, MapR, Spark 1.3.1, and hdfs 2.4.1. (It fails in local mode as well.) I've tried following the tuning and configuration advice, throwing more and more memory at the executor. My configuration is

```
conf = (SparkConf()
        .setMaster("yarn-client")
        .setAppName("pyspark-testing")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "6g") 
        .set("spark.executor.instances", 20)
        .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "1024")
        .set("spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead", "1024")
        .set("spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead", "1024")
        )
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.textFile('/data/on/hdfs/*.csv').count()  # fails every time
```

The job gets split into 893 tasks and after about 50 tasks are successfully completed, many start failing. I see `ExecutorLostFailure` in the `stderr` of the application. When digging through the executor logs, I see errors like the following:

```
15/06/24 16:54:07 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /work/analytics2/analytics/python/envs/santon/bin/python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:331)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:281)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:558)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:203)
15/06/24 16:54:07 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[stdout writer for /work/analytics2/analytics/python/envs/santon/bin/python,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:331)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(Text.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.toString(Text.java:281)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:558)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:203)
15/06/24 16:54:07 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

In the `stdout`:

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 16490"...
```

In general, I think I understand the OOM errors and troubleshooting, but I'm stuck conceptually here. This is just a simple count. I don't understand how the Java heap could possibly be overflowing when the executors have ~3G heaps. Has anyone run into this before or have any pointers? Is there something going on under the hood that would shed light on the issue?

Update:

I've also noticed that by specifying the parallelism (for example `sc.textFile(..., 1000)`) to the same number of tasks (893), then the created job has 920 tasks, all but the last of which complete without error. Then the very last task hangs indefinitely. This seems exceedingly strange!

Comment: hi, I just ran into the same issue, i have a dafarame and calling count() on it causes an executor to crash with OOME

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue I was having was actually related to a single file that was corrupted. Running a simple `cat` or `wc -l` on the file would cause the terminal to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase JAVA heap size as following on your console

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx5g"
```

You can change the values according to your data and memory size, `-Xms` Means minimum memory and `-Xmx` means max size. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Please give it a try and then ask me If there are any questions.

Comment: Thanks again for the tip. I did try it again just now and the job fails in the same way. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Where to set the "export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx5g" in spark ? whether in "Spark-defaults.conf" file or some other files.

Comment: @sara run this command on console before running the spark job. This will set the Environment Variable JAVA_OPTS as mentioned above. These are JVM options. So when you'll run Spark job it will launch with these properties.